# How can support my application support only for 7 & 10 inch tablet declaring restrication by android manifest file?

Tags: android, screen, tablet, screen-resolution

I am making an android application that will support only for 7 and 10 inch tablet.Everything fine.But i want to publish app in google play but restrict to other tablet size like 4"(800x480).

Is it possible to restrict other size.Must support only two size above.

If anyone have idea please reply.
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your app to be used on handsets (perhaps your app truly makes sense only on a large screen) or you need time to optimize it for smaller screens, you can prevent small-screen devices from downloading your app by using the  manifest element.

For example, if you want your application to be available only to tablet devices, you can declare the element in your manifest like this:

...
    
        ...

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringTabletApps